# How to use windows subsystem for linux with z shell, instead of bash, in Rstudio?

Tags: r, terminal, rstudio, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using wsl with zsh as my default shell. however, in windows Rstudio I only have access to PowerShell, CMD, and bash in the terminal settings. How can I add zsh to these options? I know that it is possible to use custom shells as terminal in Mac and Linux Rstudio but I'd like to have the same feature in windows rstudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define any preferred default shell for your WSL environment have a look here on a valid method - https://medium.com/@vinhp/set-and-use-zsh-as-default-shell-in-wsl-on-windows-10-the-right-way-4f30ed9592dc and after that, if you have WSL (properly) installed, you should be able to select [image: Global Options Terminal] Bash (WSL) as your default Terminal.

After having done some testing ie trying all sorts of workarounds on the zsh of my WSL2 I have come to the conclusion that based on this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010737148-Using-the-RStudio-Terminal?version=1.2.5033&mode=desktop#lifetime
[x] Custom shell via path to executable ==> is NOT available for Windows IDE (written at the beginning of Appendix A) 
Judging by that - on WIN RStudio Desktop 1.2.5033 - imho you can only start it via issuing `zsh` as the first command in your WSL bash terminal.

Comment: zsh is already my default shell. However, rstudio still uses bash. I couldn't find any rstudio configuration file like the files in Hyper or VS Code which the tutorial mentions.

Comment: how did you go about installing WSL? as you can tell from the screenshot if WSL and RStudio are installed in a simple manner it should 'just work' - so question becomes how does your installation differ from this "normal" setup

Comment: I don't have a problem with my wsl installation. My rstudio shows the same options like this. My question was how to add the z shell as my default instead of bash in rstudio. I'm not having a problem with wsl in rstudio. I just want to change the default wsl shell. In Mac or Linux, there is a custom option between the terminal options, which one can use to add z shell, but there is no such thing in windows. I want to know how to add this option with wsl.

Comment: Have you tried modifying your `~/.bashrc` with a `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh` at the end somewhere.

Comment: Because I am in bash and rstudio runs bash as the default, `which bash` returns `/bin/bash`. I didn't modify my `~/.bashrc` with the `chsh` command, but I think I used this command to change my default shell to zsh. In case of any misunderstanding, my default shell is zsh outside rstudio, but rstudio uses bash as its default! Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: a simple but effective answer, it works. Thank you :) If you edit your answer and add this comment as part of it, I can accept your answer as the one which solved the problem.

Comment: "Custom shell via path to executable ==> is NOT available for Windows IDE " - This is now possible in the RStudio preview release (https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/), however not clear what to put in the Custom executable to run zsh without going through bash